# Showing Datetimepicker value into Datetimepicker box from database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, crud

Hello i have database called tbl_data, that have name,address, and 'date' type of data
example : 12/5/2021 (the data saved like this in my db)
I use datetimepicker toolbox to insert date into database,
now i have 1 data of a date inside my database

I try to show the data into Datetimepicker box, the idea is when I click 1 of data from Datagridview, its show 1 set of Data (name,date,address)
my question is
with this code I **already success** showing the **name** and **address**(which is a string), how can I show the **date** into this **datetimepicker toolbox**?
thank you

```
private void dgvData_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(dgvData.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                txtName.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                //dateTimePicker1.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                // yea this code doesnt work because it convert to string but the toolbox was was not textbox but datetimepicker


            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Set `dateTimePicker1.Value` as DateTime.

Comment: @Ralf do you know how to set it in c# ? tbh I'm new to this language actually, but thank you for helping

Comment: If your datagridview is set up correctly a `dateTimePicker1.Value = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value`  should work.

Comment: @Ralf already try it its shown Error with this error code :
Error CS0266, Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

actually it works when I use dateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value; 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this if the grid uses a `DataSource`. Assuming that `tbl_data` is used as a `DataSource` to the grid, then instead of “manually” changing the data in the text boxes and date time picker, when the grid row is double clicked… you could set each text box and the date time picker's `DataBindings` property.

This will change the text in the text boxes and date time picker automatically when the user selects a different row in the grid... and your code will no longer need to "manually" set the values as your current code does. Something like…

```
txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", tbl_data, "Name");
txtAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", tbl_data, "Address");
dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Text", tbl_data, "Date");
```

Where, “Name” is the name of the “Name” column in `tbl_data` and the same applies to the “Address” column name and “Date” column name.

In addition, if the user changes the text in one of the text boxes or changes the date time picker value… then the grid will automatically reflect those changes.